# How to run official mongodb docker storing data to separate host system drive?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

I want to run the [official mongodb docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) while storing data to a separate host system drive with XFS file system mounted as `/data` on redhat linux. I want to achieve that by

`docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 -v /data:/data/db -d mongo --master --storageEngine wiredTiger`

It is my understanding that this should create a new volume mounting the host system's `/data` as `/data/db` inside the docker container and thus redirecting all access to `/data/db` to the hosts `/data`.

Doing a `docker inspect --type=container ce03...73`shows

```
"Mounts": [
{
    Source: "/data",
    Destination: "/data/db",
    Mode: "",
    RW: true
},
...
```

However doing `df` shows that `/dev/xvda1` mounted as `/` is the only fs growing, while `/dev/xvdb` mounted as `/data` remains empty. This is confirmed by `du /data` and by `ls -a /data` both showing nothing.
Now if I do `sudo du -L / | grep -E "^[0-9]{6,20}"` this shows all directories on my system with relevant byte size. Of these the only ones growing are `/proc/3071/task/3071/*`. Doing `top -p 3071` shows `mongod`. Thus instead of saving anything to `/data` the `mongod` has created a virtual volume and is storing data there. Doing `sudo du -L / | grep -E "^[0-9]{6,20}"` inside the container confirms that only `/data/db` is growing. Doing `lsblk` inside the container however does not show that anything would be mounted as `/data/db`, only two docker loops are shown being mounted as `/`. Thus `/data/db` is just a normal directory on the `/` docker image.

Why? How can I make it store data on `/data`?